# Somebody used my Apple ID on a new iPod touch

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id, messages, hacking

One of my friends got this error on his iPhone (this is the translation of message in English) :

> Your Apple ID and telephone number are in use in iMessage on a new iPod touch.

There is no iPod touch so someone used the account. What is wrong? Has somebody hacked the iPhone?

In the list of messages, there are lots of Chinese numbers and messages!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11):

The Apple ID was logged in to an iPod touch and used to send spam. The password to the account should be changed immediately and the account secured at [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com).

Comment: Thanks for answer. What was the cause of this problem? Maybe a virus? I would like to prevent any other attacks.

Comment: @Woeitg Poor passwords and phishing attacks are the most common ways Apple IDs are compromised. I suggest setting up [two factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915).

Comment: Password reuse can also be a problem if another website gets compromised. Make sure that your Apple password is unique from the passwords that you use on other websites.